# adding cliparts to image/video OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm building a web cam application as my C++ project in my college. I am integrating QT (for GUI) and OpenCV (for image processing). My application will be a simple web cam app that will access the web cam, show/record videos, capture images and other stuffs.

Well, I also want to put in a feature to add cliparts to captured images, or the streaming video. While on my research, I found out that there is no way we can overlay two images using OpenCV. The best alternative I was able to find was to reconfigure the whole image to add the clipart into the original image making it a single image. You see, that's not going to work for me as I have to be able to move the clipart and resize or rotate the clipart in my canvas. 
So, I was wondering if anybody could tell me how to achieve the effect I want most efficiently.

I would really appreciate your help. The deadline for the project submission is closing in and its a huge bump on the road to completion. PLEEEASE... RELP!!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stick a logo onto the openCV image then you simply define a region of interest (roi) on the destination video image and copy the source image to this (the details vary with each version of opencv)

If you want the logo to be semi transparent - like a TV channel ID - then you can copy the image but loop over the pixels writing a destination that is source_pixel/2 + dest_pixel/2;